# Power Calculation - Calculation of Absolute Difference

Tags: statistical-power, clinical-trials

I've been asked to undertake a power calculation because the regular statistician is not available.

I am calculating power for a trial where the endpoint will be a percentage of patients not achieving remission at a given timepoint after receiving a drug or placebo. The ratio of case:controls is 1:1

I have two columns of a table to fill out (absolute difference and sample size), and have calculated required sample size at given response rates:

```
Power    %control   %cases   Abs Diff     Sample Size
 0.8        35         5                       24
 0.8        45        15                       34
 0.8        60        30                       42
 0.8        35        15                       71
 0.8        45        25                       88
 0.8        60        40                       97
```

I calculated the sample size using the function for comparing two proportions, 'pwr.2p.test', in the R package pwr

```
P0 <- c(0.35,0.45,0.60,0.35,0.45,0.60)
P1 <- c(0.05,0.15,0.30,0.15,0.25,0.40)
lapply(1:length(P0), function(i) pwr.2p.test(h=ES.h(P0[i], P1[i]), n=NULL, power=0.8))
```

I am struggling to identify what the column 'absolute difference' means in this context. Could anyone help?